add string as a prefix to extracted string (PowerShell)
I have a script that extract set of sha256 hash from csv and save it in txt file,
I want to add string (as a prefix) before each sha256 hash
the script:
$csvfileImport = "C:\test.csv"
$txtfileExport = "C:\result.txt"
$csv = Import-CSV $csvfileImport -Delimiter ","
$csv."sha256" -replace '^.\*?\\' | Set-Content $txtfileExport

output in txt file seem like that:
58cb1ef132fbdd1855f75c2886666275d1bb75a9fb3fed88d05feee4230afd32
8fdd00243ba68cadd175af0cbaf860218e08f42e715a998d6183d7c7462a3b5b
The string that I want to add as a prefix to each sha256 hash seem like this:
curl -X POST https://xxx..:xxx..@xxxx../xx/xxx../xxx.../xx../Here the HASH256 should be inserted
How can I achieve that in my existing script ?


A simple and efficient technique for prefixing each string in an input array with a fixed string is to use -replace '^', $prefix: regex ^ matches the position at the start of each input string, and the value of $prefix is placed there, effectively prefixing the input string.
A simple example:
# -> @('prefix=foo', 'prefix=bar')
'foo', 'bar' -replace '^', 'prefix='

Thus, you're probably looking for something like:
$csv.sha256 -replace '^.\*?\\' -replace '^', 'curl -X POST https://xxx..:xxx..@xxxx../xx/xxx../xxx.../xx../' |
  Set-Content $txtfileExport


Note: If there's a chance that the prefix string contains $ characters, call .Replace('$', '$$') on it to escape them, because $ has special meaning (also) in the substitution operand of the -replace operator.

